# can we make a object of table with db builder laravel for insert query?

Tags: php, laravel

i want to create a object like this is this possible

```
$con = DB::table('table');
$con->first_name = $request->first_name;
$con->last_name = $request->last_name;
$con->email = $request->email;
$con->mobile_no = $request->mobile_no;
$con->created_at = new \DateTime();
$con->updated_at = new \DateTime();
$con->save();
```

when i run this code it gives me this

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::save()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `DB::table()`, it will return a querybuilder instance. This can chain on methods like `insert()`, `update()` or `delete()` - but you can't attach properties that you intend to later save.

I recommend that you use `DB::table('table')->insert()` and pass in an array. You can simplify it using the `only()` helper on the request.

```
$data = $request->only('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'mobile_no');
$data['created_at'] = \now();
$data['updated_at '] = \now();
DB::table('table')->insert($data);
```

Comment: Actually i want to save a record with query builder and also use setTransaltion function. can you help how i can use this setTransaltion() with query builder ?

Comment: This is relevant information and you should have included it in your question when you asked about it. But alright -- what is `setTransaltion`? Where do you call it, what is it doing? Its not a native Laravel function.